# How to add read-only SQL Textbox calculated from a SQL statement in Qgis Form field

Tags: qgis, sql

I have two tables which have a relation one to many, because the second table stores the editing history of the first table which has geometry, and they are connected through an ID.

I want to create a read-only Sql Textbox in the first table Qgis forms which value is calculated through a sql statement.

For example if i click on a geometry the field search on the second table for the rows that has the current ID and display the desire data from a certain column.

Like in this screenshot:

[image]

Where at the end of the form you can see the displayed records from the other table through a sql statement.